# Correct tense form for choosing something from given options

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-simple

My friend and I were discussing some phrases. I asked her to choose one out of three of them. When she did she said: *"I choose this one"*.

Is present simple tense valid here?
Since she has already chosen one of the phrases I think the correct answer should be either "*I chose this one*" or "*I've chosen this one*". Our conversation lasted for just 1-2 minutes.

Comment: Yes it is valid and it is quite often often used. Until she announced it she could change her mind, so the choice was not finally made untol the announcement.

Comment: She could have said _I will choose this one_ as well.